# Business Intelligence: Live reports from MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, business-intelligence

I wanted to create a (nearly) live dashboard from MySQL databases I tried PowerBI, SSRS and other similar tools but they were not as fast as I wanted. What I have in mind is the data to be updated every 1 minute or even less. Is it possible? and are there any free (or inexpensive) tools for this?

Edit: I want to build a wallboard to show some data on a big TV screen. I need it to be real-time. I tried SSRS autorefresh as well but it has a loading sign and very slow, plus PowerBI uses Azure which is very complex to configure and blocked for my country.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: You've not really covered what you've tried, because what about Power BI or SSRS didn't work for you? For example is this not fast enough?
 https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-real-time-streaming/

Comment: @Rich They didn't have realtime dashboard updates. Actually powerbi has a realtime dashboard but it uses Azure and it's so complex to setup.
I'm trying to build a wallboard and need it to be realtime.

Comment: You could build your own application with any BI tool API (including SSRS) which refreshed the visualisations less than every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a topic which has many more layers than to ask which tool is best for this case.

You have to consider

- Velocity
- Veracity
- Variety
- Kind
- Use Case

of the data. Sure, this is usually only being recounted if talking about Big Data, but will give you a feeling about the size and complexity of data.

**Loading**

Is the data being loaded and you "just" use it? Or do you also need to load it realtime or near-realtime (for clarification [read this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075709/creating-real-time-datawarehouse/40081660#40081660))?

**Polling/Pushing**

Do you want to poll data every x seconds or minutes? Or do you want to work event based? What are the requirements which will need you to show data this fast?

**Use case**

Do you want to show financial data? Do you need to show data about error and system logs of servers and applications? Do you want to generate insights as soon as a visitor of a webpage is making a request?

**Conclusion**

When thinking about those questions, keep in mind this should just be a hint to go into one direction or another. Depending on the data and the use case, you might use an ELK stack (for logs), Power BI (for financial data) or even some scripts (for billing).